# Jquery Mouseenter Click to Remove Class Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really hoping someone can help. I have an unordered list of anchors that fades in opacity  (the css defaults it to 0.7) on on mouseenter, and out again on mouseleave.

On click, I want to add a class that makes the opacity stay at full.
Got that far, but removing the class from the matched elements doesn't work at the moment -  the other items that have had the class stay at full opacity, too.

Here is the Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#nav a").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $("#nav a").click(function () {
                $(".activeList").removeClass("activeList"); //THIS PART ISN'T WORKING   
                $(this).addClass("activeList");
            });
        });

        $("#nav a").mouseleave(function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("activeList")) {
                $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.7);
            }
        });
    });
```

I think it's because I'm stuck in the element because of mouseenter and can only affect (this). Have tried .bind/.unbind, have tried the add/remove class on it's own (it worked) and a few other things, but no luck so far!
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The syntax of the line that doesn't work is fine, a quick test proves that it works (in my test anyway). What about it doesn't work, is it not removing the class from the previously clicked element? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: Yeah, not removing class from previously clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#nav a").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
        });

        $("#nav a").click(function () {
            $(".activeList").removeClass("activeList"); //THIS PART ISN'T WORKING   
            $(this).addClass("activeList");
        });

        $("#nav a").mouseleave(function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("activeList")) {
                $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.7);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: looks like it should work.  For more efficiency you can also chain the 3 sections since they all refer to `$("#nav a")`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (it's almost the same code but laid out differently, with some tweaks):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#nav a").hover(function(e) { //On hover in
        $(this).fadeTo("slow",1);
    },function(e) { //On hover out
        if(!($(this).hasClass("activeList")))
        {
            $(this).fadeTo("fast",0.7);
        }
    }).click(function(e) { //On click
        $("#nav a").removeClass("activeList");
        $(this).addClass("activeList");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Smokey. Thanks, I like the semantic nature of this code, but it still doesn't remove the opacity. Have fixed and posted, but going to work my solution into yours. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Realised that the opacity wasn't coming off until hover, maybe because page doesn't refresh, don't know. Have edited my own code to make it work, but think I might work my solution into yours as yours is more semantic. Here's what I got:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav a").mouseenter(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("activeList")) // Added IF here, only had it on 
                                         // mouseleave originally
        {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 1);
        }
          $("#nav a").click(function () {
          $(".activeList").stop().removeClass("activeList"); 
          $(this).stop().stop().addClass("activeList");
          $("#nav a").stop().not(".activeList").fadeTo("fast",0.7);
   //The class came off, but the opacity didn't fade because no page refresh..?
   //Added extra animation eliminating selected with .not to fix

        });
        });
            //THE REST IS SUPERFLUOUS
        $("#nav a").mouseleave(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("activeList")) 
             {
           $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0.7);
             }
    });
});
```

Had to add a few .stop parts in mine, too, because multiple hover was not good.
Will stop posting now, and maybe just pop one comment on yours to say if I managed to integrate my answer into your neater code.

Thank you all so much for posting, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the opacity is added by adding to the element's style attribute so removing the class doesn't help, try clearing the style as well like this:

```
    $("#nav a").click(function () {
        $(".activeList").attr("style", "");
        $(".activeList").removeClass("activeList");
        $(this).addClass("activeList");
    });
```